# Sketching regions is complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

When sektching the region $\left|\frac{2z-1}{z+i}\right|$$\geq$1
on the argrand diagram,

how should we go about identifying the region, should we take

$\left|2z-1\right|\geq\left|z+i\right|$ or try multiplying by the
conjugate in the left hand side modulus?

ie something like $\left|\frac{2z-1}{z+i}\frac{z-1}{z-i}\right|$$\geq1.$
nothing is jumping out at me either way.

Comment: use the Cartesian coordinates $z=x+iy$

Comment: @Hamou Use the answers section to answer questions. Comments are to suggest improvements or to ask for more information.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**:

Yes, write it as $|2z-1| \ge |z+\mathrm{i}|$. This is true, if and only if $|2z-1|^2 \ge |z+\mathrm{i}|^2$.

Replace $z$ by $x+\mathrm{i}y$.

Collect the real and imaginary parts inside each modulus.

Apply the definition for the modulus: $|u+\mathrm{i}v|^2 = u^2 + v^2$

Expand your brackets, and take all of the $x$s and $y$s over to one side.

Complete the square on the $x$ terms and $y$ terms separately.

You'll find that you have either the inside or the outside of a circle, including the circle itself.

I get the radius of the circle to be a multiple of $\sqrt{5}$ and the centre is in the upper-right quadrant.